# How can i get the latest record of my tabel

Tags: mysql

How can i get the latest date out of a tabel. Perhaps it is better if i show you what i mean.

This is my current tabel output

```
TransactionID          Title           Date
23132                  Locaton         2013-05-17 10:02:04
23131                  Novuel          2013-05-16 16:26:45
23130                  Novuel          2013-05-16 11:41:21
23129                  Locaton         2013-05-15 15:02:47
23128                  Mama Rosa       2013-05-15 14:42:44
23127                  Locaton         2013-05-14 18:21:32
23126                  Rohan           2013-05-14 12:46:56
```

And this is the desired output:

```
TransactionID          Title           Date
23132                  Locaton         2013-05-17 10:02:04
23131                  Novuel          2013-05-16 16:26:45
23128                  Mama Rosa       2013-05-15 14:42:44
23126                  Rohan           2013-05-14 12:46:56
```

As you can se i only want the latest date from each title out of mysql.

And this is how i tried so far to get the desired output:

```
    ("SELECT t.transactionid,
       ct.title,
       max(t.transactiontime)
FROM exp_channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN transactions AS t ON (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
WHERE t.transactiontime IN
    (SELECT max(t.transactiontime)
     FROM transactions AS t)
GROUP BY ct.entry_id
ORDER BY t.transactiontime DESC");
```

Comment: No, in demo i also have 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from t t1
where 
NOT EXISTS (select transactionID 
                from t where t.Title=t1.title
                         and t.date>t1.date)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/1c8bb/1)

Comment: Valex, what about the other table?

Comment: @Zaz : That is what I was talking about. You said from tabl1 you want output like tabl2. But in query you have two tables exp_channel_titles & exp_channel_titles.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT t1.transactionid, ct.title, t1.transactiontime
FROM exp_channel_titles as ct
LEFT JOIN
(Select t.* from transactions as t 
INNER join (SELECT max(TransactionID) FROM transactions group by Title having     transactiontime=max(transactiontime) ) temp
ON temp.TransactionID= t.TransactionID) as t1
on ct.entry_id = t1.restaurant_id
```

Comment: Hey modified group by clause now try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(t.transactionid) AS TRANSACTION_ID, ct.title, MAX(t.transactiontime)
FROM exp_channel_titles as ct
LEFT JOIN transactions as t 
on (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
GROUP BY CT.TITLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp)

not sure if it is what you mean